# Table of Contents(TOC) Widget for ArcGIS JavaScript API in Legacy?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents

I want to develop a legend using Table of Contents(TOC) Widget for ArcGIS JavaScript API in Legacy code.

I have tried its development by following the steps in the documentation of TOC Widget for ArcGIS JavaScript API but it seems that they are only for AMD code type. Also I haven't been able to find any example of this widget in Legacy code.

Does somebody know if it is possible? Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked [this TOC widget?](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109) it has commented source code and the older versions are in the source control too so you must be able to find some legacy code - it can help you to get ideas building your own, or to modify this one to suit your needs.

i have not seen any esri documentation on older TOC versions before the one you mention.